# is there a way to send a notification when a youtube video status changes?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

Looking at the https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications it only triggers when:

- uploads video
- change to title
- change to description

is there a way in which to send a notification if the status of the video changes from published to unpublished for example?

Comment: No as the documentation states its not going to notify you if the status is changed.   However if you want to check it now and then the etag will probably change.